# in React if I want to conditionally render a component based on screen size is it better to use State or CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

Lets say I have a navigation bar, and for Mobile its a hamburger menu, and for desktop its a standard nav bar with links.

I could use CSS media queries to display none for certain screen size, or I could use react hooks useState and useEffect with some event listeners.

For starters it seems way easier to create the CSS solution, but is there a benefit to either or?

I've tried both of these my question is more so about performance or what is seen as the most preferred way to achieve this effect.

Comment: My general rule of thumb is to use media queries where I can, and then to fall back to modifying the React tree when I can't get enough done there. The primary concern is that subscribing to resizes in JS may result in excessive re-rendering unless done carefully.